# Change DNS servers in an OpenWrt router from command line

Tags: router, dns, openwrt, uci

How can I change the DNS settings using the command line in an OpenWrt router?
I see these files in the [documentation of "The UCI system"](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/uci):

- `/etc/config/ddns`
- `/etc/config/ipset-dns`

But I also see dnsmasq installed

but not sure which can change the DNS servers on the router

My end goal is to add a cron job that adds a custom DNS server for couple of hours per day, then revert to the original DNS.

I've found the following commands; can anybody explain?

```
uci set network.wan.dns='<list of space-separated DNS server IPs>'
uci commit network
reload_config
```

and

```
uci set network.wan.peerdns='0'
uci del network.wan.dns
uci add_list network.wan.dns='9.9.9.9'
uci add_list network.wan.dns='149.112.112.112'
uci commit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenWRT documentation provides an example of this configuration, see https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp_configuration

```
# Configure DNS provider
uci set network.wan.peerdns="0"
uci set network.wan.dns="8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
uci set network.wan6.peerdns="0"
uci set network.wan6.dns="2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844"
uci commit network
service network reload
```